# Scroll inside of fixed container until specific end

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a `.top-container` which consists of 2 div's. The first one has a height of 100vh and the second 20vh. After this top-container comes a further div - let's call it `.test-div`.

I want the top-container to scroll until the end of its second element - in total it should scroll to 120vh. Scrolling further I want the test-div to overlap the top-container.

I tried to achieve that by changing the top-container's position to fixed, but **it solely shows the first element** with 100vh.

```
.top-container {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

You can find my full code in the following stack: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-48iudo